# What is wrong with this syntax?

Tags: c#

```
    public static void PullData(Hashtable source)
    {            
        IPGlobalProperties ipProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
        //IPEndPoint[] endPoints = ipProperties.GetActiveTcpListeners();
        TcpConnectionInformation[] tcpConnections = ipProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections();

        foreach (TcpConnectionInformation info in tcpConnections)
        {
            if (!(info.RemoteEndPoint.Address.ToString() == "192" || info.RemoteEndPoint.Address.ToString() == "127"))
            {
                source.Add(info.RemoteEndPoint.Address.ToString(), new IPInstance(
                  new string[info.LocalEndPoint.Port.ToString(), info.RemoteEndPoint.Port.ToString()],
                  info.RemoteEndPoint.Address.ToString(),
                  Dns.GetHostEntry(info.RemoteEndPoint.Address.ToString())
                  ));
            }
        }
    }
```

I keep getting Error    1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like your array initializer is messed up :)

```
new string[info.LocalEndPoint.Port.ToString(), info.RemoteEndPoint.Port.ToString()],
```

maybe you meant

```
new string[]{info.LocalEndPoint.Port.ToString(), info.RemoteEndPoint.Port.ToString()},
```

?

Comment: To add to this, the reason you get a type conversion error is because you were creating a 2 dimensional array, and the syntax for that is new string[length,otherLength]; Which means the program was trying to convert your port strings to ints for length.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a two-dimentional array here

```
new string[info.LocalEndPoint.Port.ToString(), info.RemoteEndPoint.Port.ToString()]
```

To initialize two-dimensional array of string you need to provide two integers (number of rows and number of columns). What you provide is two strings: local endpoint converted to string and remote endpoint converted to string as well